# Insert statement that checks for duplicate before insert

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, duplicates

I need to make a insert but only if similar record don't exists
for example:

> INSERT INTO requests ('user_id','subject','text','time') VALUES (56,'test','test 1234',6516516)

but to check if there are same 'subject' and 'text' in another record to:

1. not insert anything
2. update 'time' and 'user_id'

I need sql for both cases because I'm no sure at this moment what I'm going to use.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean always set the request to the latest user?

Comment: For 2. - yes ... but for 1. I don't want to do anything if there is simila record.

Comment: I think the user will get quite mad if his requests overwrite by another guy, correct?

Comment: @ajreal nope... this will be read by admin so nobody cares who exactly post the request. Actually I think that the user_id can be a set... so the next id to be added to the set.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO requests ('user_id','subject','text','time') 
VALUES (56,'test','test 1234',6516516)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = VALUES(time), user_id = VALUES(user_id)
```

Have the relevant columns set to index UNIQUE.

This will insert a row, but if subject or text (or both) already exist, you instead update the existing row with given `time` and `user_id`

Comment: 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'. How can we do the DUPLICATE check based on 2 columns like user_id and subject ?

Comment: This relies on the relevant fields being unique/primary and updates if it's unable to insert existing one. In your case I'm not sure what is unique in the subject. A table with unique user_id and subject_id could trigger ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: I had to ALTER my table's primary key and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

First, you can do the update.  If the record doesn't exist, nothing will happen...

```
UPDATE
  requests
SET
  user_id = 56,
  time = 6516516
WHERE
  subject = 'test'
  AND text = 'test 1234'
```

Then you can use SELECT instead of VALUES in the INSERT.  If the record already exists, nothing will be inserted...

```
INSERT INTO
  requests (
    user_id,
    subject,
    text,
    time
  )
SELECT
  56,
  'test',
  'test 1234',
  6516516
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM requests WHERE subject = 'test' AND text = 'test 1234')
```

Comment: This is a great idea, however, it is not syntactically correct for MySQL.  Also, it can be more efficient by attempting an "insert ignore" first and checking for the last_insert_id (assuming your table has an autoincrement field).  If a value is returned, it inserted, so you're done.  If it's null, the insert was ignored due to a matching key, so perform the update. `insert ignore requests (user_id, subject, text, time) values (56, 'test', 'test 1234', 6516516);`

Comment: I use this solution when I cannot use unique index or not working with IDs, only you have syntax error, there should be `select 56, ... **FROM ANY_TABLE** ... `

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IGNORE` command

For example, use like this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO requests ('user_id','subject','text','time') VALUES (56,'test','test 1234',6516516)
```

instead of,

```
INSERT INTO requests ('user_id','subject','text','time') VALUES (56,'test','test 1234',6516516)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_id, text from users where user_id = @user_id AND text = @text) BEGIN
   INSERT INTO users ....
ELSE
   UPDATE users SET xyz=uvw where user_id = @user_id AND text = @text
END
```

Comment: are those `@` symbols are for variable, as in php I can use dollar sign `$`, secondly can you please explain a bit about your query, I think I know what begin and end means in transaction but `IF` and `ELSE`, are they mysql keywords and can I directly use that query in `mysqli_query` function

Comment: I believe that this answer uses syntax for stored procedures in SQL Server (I'm looking at the `@` symbol).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your query from

> INSERT INTO requests ('user_id','subject','text','time') VALUES (56,'test','test 1234',6516516)

To,

> REPLACE INTO requests ('user_id','subject','text','time') VALUES (56,'test','test 1234',6516516)

This will add a small delay to the execution, but it is more efficient than any other method

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `REPLACE` mysql statement?