# How to check if record exists in another table and if not then add

Tags: sql, database, select, exists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert statement that checks for duplicate before insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312058/insert-statement-that-checks-for-duplicate-before-insert)

I'd like to check if a building id exists in the issue log table using the foreign key b_id. And if it does not exist then i would like to add it to the issue log table. 
I have the code below but this only checks to see which buildings are not in the issue log table...how can i do the insert? Thanks a lot. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

```
select b.b_id from building 
where not exists(select b.b_id from issue_log as l where b._id = l.b_id)
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
INSERT INTO issue_log(b_id)
SELECT b.b_id FROM building b
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT l.b_id FROM issue_log AS l WHERE b.b_id = l.b_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `IF NOT EXISTS` or if you'd like to potentially do an update use `MERGE` which will make the decision whether to do an insert, update, or optionally a delete based on rules you set in the statment. It's quite useful once you get the syntax down

MSDN: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.105).aspx