# How to validate duplicate entry in SQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to validate and show a message to the user whenever a duplicate entry is submitted. Also, I am using this validation to generate an entry in my database whenever a user registers for the first time. I'm aware my code might be SQL Injection compromised, but I'm not worried about that in this exercise.

My table has a primary key "RUT", it is unique. I need to validate if the user is submitting a RUT already in the database.

Code:

```
$datos; 

    @$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","speedomart");

    if($db){
        $sql = "insert into cliente values('".$rut."','".$nombre."','".$apellido."','".$correo."','".$pass."')";
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query ->execute();
        if(mysql_errno() == 1062){
                   $datos = array('mensaje' => "no fue posible insertar datos");
                   echo json_encode($datos);
         }
        else{    
              $sql2 = "insert into carrito values(NULL,'".$rut."')";
              $query = $db->prepare($sql2);
              $query ->execute();    
              $datos = array('mensaje' => "Registrado correctamente");
              echo json_encode($datos);
           };
    }
   else{
          $datos = array('mensaje' => "No hay conexion.");
          echo json_encode($datos);
    };
```

Comment: Add a unique index spanning multiple columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to avoid duplicate entry into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219786/best-way-to-avoid-duplicate-entry-into-mysql-database)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert statement that checks for duplicate before insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312058/insert-statement-that-checks-for-duplicate-before-insert)

Comment: None of those answers are similar to my problem and question. I'm trying to use the validation for a purpose.

Comment: What do you consider a "*duplicate entry*"? Two clients with the same RUT?

Comment: Yes, that the primary key. I what to validate that to deliver a message and also generate a new entry to a different table.

Comment: Why don't you `SELECT` from that table an entry `WHERE rut = $rut` and check if it returns something?

Comment: What would be the sintaxis for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that it is the email which can not be duplicate. So when you submit the form you can first select the data using the particular email id as follows:

```
    $sql = "select *from table where email ='".$email."'";
            $query = $db->prepare($sql);
            $user_array = $query ->execute();

    if(count($user_array) > 0){
       //You can use insert query here 
    }else{
       //email already exist.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF Exists(SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE FieldValue='$') THEN
   --record exists, get ID you need.
   BEGIN
     SELECT TableID FROM Table WHERE FieldValue='$';
   END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table (FieldValue) VALUES('$');
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS TableID;
END;
END IF;
```

Comment: I happen to like to use `IF EXISTS`, because to me it makes it even more obvious to the (human) reader what the query is supposed to be doing . . .

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

(1) If "the nature of the data is" that there should be no duplicates for any field or particular combination of fields, then you *should* define a `UNIQUE` index so that SQL will never allow a duplicate to be inserted by any means.  *(You will not be able to create such an index if any duplicates now exist.)*  This is a "data integrity rule" which SQL will enforce for you.

(2) SQL injection is trivially easy to avoid here, and you should always do so.  Simply use *parameters* in your SQL query text:  `?` (without quotation marks ... this not a one-character literal string).  Now, you simply supply an array of parameter-value substitutions each time you execute the prepared SQL.  The parameters will be substituted left-to-right in order of occurrence.  This not only avoids injection problems but also is more efficient:  the statement does not have to be re-prepared each time.  Please just get in the habit of doing this all the time ... you'll be glad you did.